# Can I have MacPorts mongodb run only when I log in as a particular user?

Tags: macos, mongodb, macports

I've installed mongodb with `sudo port install mongodb`, and started it using `sudo port load mongodb`. This works fine, but when I log out and log in as a different user (I have different accounts for work and non-work), mongodb is still running.

Can I make it run only when I log in as my work user, and then close when I log out?

Answer (score 1):

When starting MongoDB with `sudo port load mongodb`, the daemon will run as a dedicated system user. The daemon process has no connection to your personal user account and will therefore not be shut down when you log out.

As an alternative, you can also run MongoDB as your own user. For that you will need a new directory where it should keep its data and log files. This example will use `$HOME/mongodb`, but you could put this anywhere else as you like.

First set up this new directory once:

```
mkdir -p $HOME/mongodb/db
```

To start MongoDB, you can use the following command that you could also wrap into a shell script to avoid having to remember it:

```
mongod --dbpath $HOME/mongodb/db --logpath $HOME/mongodb/mongodb.log --logappend
```

Now just leave this Terminal window open. You can stop the MongoDB instance with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

If you prefer to monitor activity more directly, just leave out the `--logpath` parameter and argument. MongoDB will then log what it is doing right in the Terminal on standard output, but only a limited number of lines will be available in the scrollback buffer of the Terminal window.